# Search filter cannot take sort function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-development-server

I am new in React and was trying to make a AutoCompleteText Search Box from a youtube tutorial[React Beginners Tutorial - Build an Autocomplete Text Box](https://youtu.be/NnpISZANByg) for my Web Application(https://github.com/pydevsg/Bank-Filter-App). But it is showing me this error when I am running it through localhost.

But it is showing me this error when I am running it through localhost.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined
>
> AutoCompleteText.onTextChanged
>
> 14 |   let suggestions = [];
>
> 15 |   if (value.length > 0) {
>
> 16 |     const regex = new RegExp(`${value}`, `i`);
>
> 17 |     suggestions = this.items.sort().filter(v => regex.test(v));
>
> 18 |   }
>
> 19 |   this.setState(() => ({ suggestions, text: value }));
>
> 20 | };

I expect that the SearchBox should be able to show all the data as per my DataTable.

Comment: Took a quick look at what you're passing to the Autocomplete, make sure your bank.js import actually comes out to something.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I see what your problems are, you've got components rendering unessesarily and not rendering the ones that you need.

Firstly:

```js
import App from "./App"; // Import your app

// Make it display the App
var displayDropdown = (
  <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>
    <App />
  </div>
);

// Get rid of all other ReactDOM renders
ReactDOM.render(displayDropdown, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Then in `DataTable.js`, get rid of your `AutoCompleteText` component, it's not doing anything and is what's causing it to blow up since you're not passing any props to it. If you want to keep the one in the `DataTable` component then you need to pass the bank array to it just like you're doing in `App.js`.

That should get you closer to where you want to be.

Comment: Thanks Anthony Z but the sole purpose of my  error haven't yet solved. I am still getting the error and unable to solve the same.

Comment: Make sure you are passing bank to any AutoCompleteText components. Particularly in DataTable.js